# how fast does a Sapphire R9 280X Varpor-X Tri-X can and how can i calculate the bitcoin i can have pers day?

Tags: transactions

as above i'm wondering that how fast (mh/s) can a R9 280X can and how can i calculate the bitcoin i can have per days because i'm newb to this mining

Answer (score 1):

Hashrate for the Saphire can be found here:

https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison

Don't bother GPU mining, especially for SHA-256 (bitcoin). You can blow one of those out of the water with a $20 used USB ASIC on ebay. The days of casual mining are over, you will be operating at a loss unless you have some of the cheapest electricity in the world and a large mining setup.

Comment: well i'm just try for a month, and i'm in Vietnam, and it's just 2,000VND for a 1KW, and 1$ is 22,797VND in my country, that sound crazy :D